# Maximizing a sum of 2 square roots, a curious symmetry w.r.t. permutations of parameters

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, permutations, area, maxima-minima

Suppose $a,b,c,p,q,r$ are some positive real parameters, none of which exceeds the sum of the other five. Consider a real-valued function of a real variable $x$ defined as
$$\!\!\!\!\small{\begin{align}f(x)&=\sqrt{(a+b+c-x) (x-a+b+c) (x+a-b+c) (x+a+b-c)}\\&+\unicode{x200a}\sqrt{(p+q+r-x) (x-p+q+r) (x+p-q+r) (x+p+q-r)}.\end{align}}\tag{$\small\diamondsuit$}$$
We assume that it is only defined for positive values of $x$ such that both expressions under the square roots are also positive. We are interested in the largest value attained by $f(x)$. It is possible to prove that it happens when $x$ is one of the roots of the septic equation
$$\!\!\!\!\small{\begin{align}&(a+b+c-x)(x-a+b+c)(x+a-b+c)(x+a+b-c)(p\, x+q\, r)(q\, x+p\, r)(r\, x+p\, q)=\\&(p+q+r-x)(x-p+q+r)(x+p-q+r)(x+p+q-r)(a\, x+b\, c)(b\, x+a\, c)(c\, x+a\, b).\end{align}}\tag{$\small\spadesuit$}$$
It is obvious that the largest value of $f(x)$ is the same for all permutations of the triples $(a,b,c)$ and $(p,q,r)$ because the parameters within each triple appear in the definition of $f(x)$ in a symmetrical way.

But it looks like the largest value actually remains the same for *all permutations* of the sextuple $(a,b,c,p,q,r)$, although the value of $x$ that maximizes $f(x)$ can be different for different permutations. This property seems to not be immediately obvious from the definition. How can we prove it?

Comment: Those square roots look remarkably similar to [Heron's Formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Heron%27s_Formula).  I'd be interested if there is a way to interpret it geometrically.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed related to it. $\frac14\sqrt{(a+b+c-d) (d-a+b+c) (d+a-b+c) (d+a+b-c)}$ is the largest possible area of a quadrilateral with sides of lengths $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Not immediately obvious if/how this helps, but for a cyclic $\,abcx\,$ (which maxcimizes the area): $\;bx+ac=de = 4R^2 \sin A \sin B\,$, $\;ax+bc=\frac{2S}{\sin B}\,$, $\;cx+ab=\frac{2S}{\sin A}\,$, so:

$$
\small{\frac{(a+b+c-x)(x-a+b+c)(x+a-b+c)(x+a+b-c)}{(a\, x+b\, c)(b\, x+a\, c)(c\, x+a\, b)} = \frac{16 S^2}{4S^2 \cdot 4R^2} = \frac{1}{R^2}
}$$

Comment: Related: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrahmaguptasFormula.html, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicHexagon.html, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicPolygon.html, https://www.drking.org.uk/hexagons/misc/polymax.html.

Comment: A geometric approach seems the way to go. $\frac14f(x)$ is the total area of two cyclic quadrilaterals sharing a common side of length $x$. The maximum value of $\frac14f(x)$ is the largest area of a hexagon with sides of lengths $a,b,c,p,q,r$ and a diagonal of length $x$ that divides it into two cyclic quadrilateral parts. The equation $({\small\spadesuit})$ means that both cyclic quadrilateral parts are inscribed in circles of the same radius.  Because a hexagon must be cyclic to maximize its area, those circles must be actually the same circle.